# How does Qt QML Javascript manage memory?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have a question about Qt Javascript.

In most case, javascript use reference counting or mark and sweep for garbage collection. I'm curious about how Qt does it.

Especially, I can pass a javascript object to C++ using QJSValue. I want to pass javascript callback function to C++ method, and asynchronously call that function.(for example, http response) Is it safe because QJSValue has reference to the object? I can't be sure.

If Qt use mark and sweep garbage collection, then how dose it can mark the referene in C++ side? so does Qt javascript use reference counting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: JavaScript part here will be using whatever scripting host OS uses, MSHTA in case of Windows. Qt itself doesn't have garbage collection or defragmentation, it uses C++ runtime.

Comment: Sometimes it just doesn't: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50319

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html

> Note that a QJSValue for which isObject() is true only carries a reference to an actual object; copying the QJSValue will only copy the object reference, not the object itself. If you want to clone an object (i.e. copy an object's properties to another object), you can do so with the help of a for-in statement in script code, or QJSValueIterator in C++.

QJSValue carries a reference.